# Sinatra + Rack:Session:Pool

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am using Rack:Session:Pool for memory based sessions. I would like
to access the pool instance variables that is contacted in
Rack:Session:Pool so I can see all the active session and contained data. How can I do
that from within Sinatra or on the irb prompt.

my initial thought was ::Sinatra:Application::Rack::Session:Pool, but
that seems to give me the class and not the current instance so the
pool variable is not accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing this just for development/debugging/poking at code with a stick, you could do some monkey patching and make the pool a global variable.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'yaml'

class Rack::Session::Pool
  def initialize app,options={}
    super
    $pool=@pool=Hash.new
    @mutex=Mutex.new
  end
end

use Rack::Session::Pool

get '/' do
  y $pool
  ''
end
```

Or, you could write a wrapper fn that does that for you.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'yaml'

module PoolWrapper
  def self.new *args
    middleware = Rack::Session::Pool.new *args
    $pool=middleware.pool
    middleware
  end
end

use PoolWrapper
# same as above 
#...
```

For debugging, the monkey patch is probably cleaner as you don't have to change the `use` call and you can wrap the monkeypatch with something that checks the environment so it is only used during devel,etc,etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The global variable is 'nil' within in the scope of the sinatra application. Also, I believe the global variable is the above example is being passed by value not reference so when the session a stored in the @pool they will not reflect in the $pool

Comment: It is passed by value, but the value is a pointer to the same hash object. It shouldn't be `nil` unless it was not assigned.

Comment: Well I tested the "monkey patch" version again and it worked!. I believe the issue was that call "y $pool" returned and empty string. I just called "$pool.to_yaml" and it worked.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I like using `y`, it is like `p` only it outputs the result of `to_yaml` instead of `inspect` which I think is more readable.